# Ubuntu Software updates error on 12.04 LTS version

Tags: ubuntu, software-updates

When I update these packages I am getting the following error, please find the attached screenshot.

[image: http://prntscr.com/fpg1cu]

Can anyone help us on this?

Comment: ubuntu 12.04 is dead ubuntu Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS has support untill April 2019. The current LTS-Version is 16.04. My advice is save your data's and install Ubunu 16.04 fresh. `ubuntu-support-status`

Answer (score 0):

When you add a ppa repository to your software sources, you should also add the GPG key of that repository.

If you do not, Software (the update program) will request permission to install any packages from the ppa repository using this "scary" dialog. Without GPG key, Software cannot trust the repo.

See this for for how to add a GPG key of the repo: https://askubuntu.com/questions/291035/how-to-add-a-gpg-key-to-the-apt-sources-keyring